# Extended scientific abstract: should it include full results?

Tags: research-process, conference, abstract

I'm writing an extended abstract for a conference prize. There are few instructions and it's the first time ever that I write one so I'm a little woried about it. The only restriction regards the length, but other than that no instructions are given.

My question is: am I expected to give my full results? I'd rather not give my analytical results of my analysis since I still have to publish them.

Comment: Are extended abstracts from previous years of this conference (or similar conferences) publicly available? Can you read them and see to what extent they include full results?

Comment: unfortunately no

Answer (score 3):

If the organisers required an extended abstract to assign a prize, try to make their job easier. :)

I would include a specific section called `Results` or `Preliminary Results` in which you gently introduce some of the most significant results you obtained so far: objective/numerical evidences that your work is reliable, has reached a mature stage to deserve a prize.